# How do you convert a callback to a future in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, future

In Javascript you can convert a callback to a promise with:

```js
function timeout(time){
   return new Promise(resolve=>{
      setTimeout(()=>{
         resolve('done with timeout');
      }, time)
   });
}
```

Is that possible in Flutter?

Example:

```dart
// I'd like to use await syntax, so I make this return a future
Future<void> _doSomething() async {
    // I'm call a function I don't control that uses callbacks
    // I want to convert it to async/await syntax (Future)
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
        // I want to do stuff in here and have the return of
        // `_doSomething` await it
        await _doSomethingElse();
    });
}

await _doSomething();
// This will currently finish before _doSomethingElse does.
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  A `Future` is just a notification that an asynchronous operation completes.  If your callback is synchronous, you don't need to be notified. If it's asynchronous, it will already return a `Future`.  What is your ultimate goal?  If you just want to delay calling a synchronous callback, just wrap it in an asynchronous function that does `await Future. delayed(...)` first.

Comment: Callbacks and Futures are two different patterns for executing code that depends on an asynchronous operation. This question covers the case where you're working with a library that only provides a callback syntax that you'd like to convert to async/await syntax. I've provided an example for clarity. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, ok.  Yes, that makes sense now, and yes, you would want to use a `Completer` for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer from [this post](https://medium.com/@brianschardt/dart-turn-callback-function-into-a-future-95f54431936b).

```dart
Future time(int time) async {
    
  Completer c = new Completer();
  new Timer(new Duration(seconds: time), (){
    c.complete('done with time out');
  });

  return c.future;
}
```

So to accommodate the example listed above:

```dart
Future<void> _doSomething() async {
    Completer completer = new Completer();
    
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
        
        await _doSomethingElse();
        
        completer.complete();
    });
    return completer.future
}

await _doSomething();
// This won't finish until _doSomethingElse does.
```

Answer (score -1):

saying that we have a normal method that return just a value like this:

```
int returnValueMethod() {
 return 42;
}
```

we can make it a `Future` by assigning it directly to `Future.value()` like this:

```
Future.value(returnValueMethod());
```